# IIS Redirect in Localhost

Tags: c#, redirect, iis, web-config, cross-domain

I have 2 localhost sites with dummy index page in each site.
URL's are : [www.testsite1.com:5005](http://www.testsite1.com:5005) and [www.testsite2.com:5006](http://www.testsite2.com:5006)
I am trying to redirect when I hit [www.testsite1.com:5005](http://www.testsite1.com:5005) to "www.testsite2.com:5006" in IIS

Following is my testsite1 web.config for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)" />                  
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.testsite2.com:5006" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

</system.webServer>

When I hit the [www.testsite1.com:5005](http://www.testsite1.com:5005) it is redirecting to "https://www.testsite2.com/" but I am expecting redirect to "www.testsite2.com:5006"

How to avoid http to https? and include the port 5006 in the redirect?

Comment: At the beginning, please don't use web browsers for such testing which can cache redirection, but command line tools such as `curl`. Once you are sure server side rules are correctly configured, then you can go back and dig into browser side settings.

Comment: The community member has made it very clear. Browser cache will interfere test. Your web.config is fine. Generally, IIS will not redirect to HTTPS without configuration. I think the problem is with browser.  Some web browsers use https by default. So it cannot redirect to port 5006.